# Google chat video - Fedora / Google Chrome

Tags: fedora, video, chrome, chat

The webcam is working, because I can see me with the "Cheese" app.

I installed: `google-talkplugin_current_i386.rpm`.

Then I opened Chrome, and this is what I see:

```
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUopi.png<br>
```

The webcam part is black.

What can I do, so that "google chat" will recognize my webcam?

I've been on this for hours and I'm tired now. Can someone help?

- I tried to disable all plugins, it's the same.
- I tried it in Firefox. It freezes.

The only problem is the video part. Why can't I see the webcams picutre?

Comment: In firefox, can you post the details of Flash from the page `about:plugins`  Be sure to expand the details tab on the upper right.

Comment: Actually, my last comment applies to Chrome, but Firefox also has an about:plugins page.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [this](http://ubuntu-install.blogspot.com/2011/07/google-and-webcam.html#comment-form). It works for me with Fedora fc14.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest flash plugin?

Also, you can give [Gnash](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnash/) a try, see what happens :)

Comment: i was trying with Google Chrome so it has a built-in up-to-date flash plugin!